# Wordpress Image Upload Error - Specified file failed upload test

Tags: wordpress, image, image-uploading

I have been trying for hours to get this working.

WP image upload works fine for single image without using `multiple` tag.

But when tried to to upload multiple images after changing the php code for multiple images (array) and adding `multiple` tag, show error:

### Specified file failed upload test.

File upload data is coming through JSON which works fine when printed.

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
    if(!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')){
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    }

    foreach($styledNameData as $nameData){
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($nameData);
        // It Prints
        //Array
        //(
        //  [name] => A_Front.png
        //  [type] => image/png
        //  [tmp_name] => C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php5BFB.tmp
        //  [error] => 0
        //  [size] => 32901
        //)

        $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload($nameData, $upload_overrides);
    }
    if($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($movefile);
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($movefile['error']);
    }
```

HTML is:

```
<form id="imagesForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
    <input id="uploadfile" type="file" class="button button-secondary" name="uploadfile[]" multiple />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="shpg_image_upload" />
    <input type="submit" id="uploadImages" name="uploadImages" class="btn-medium col-sms-5 col-sm-3" value="UPLOAD" />
</form>
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can often happen if the $_FILES array is empty. The $_FILES array can be empty for a couple different reasons and more often than not it is because one of the following server settings needs to be changed.

```
file_uploads=Off <--- Set this to On

post_max_size=8M <-- increase this to be larger than your image

upload_max_filesize=2M <-- increase this to be larger than your image
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. The accepted answer isn't really correct. If you look at wp-admin/includes/ at the function in question _wp_handle_upload, the check that fires this error is simply a check for is_uploaded_file - whether the file exists. Testing for file size and type doesn't happen until after. So no - the solution if you're getting this message won't be changing those parameters.

I ended up debugging this by looking at the $_FILES array when it comes back from my form, inside my admin_post action. The way you have your form setup, I assume it will be the same as mine. The $_FILES array is not in the format that is expected here, and because wp_handle_upload is being passed an index to the $_FILES array - the $file variable at the point in the code where this error fires is NULL if you dump it out (file.php:808).

My $_FILES array looked like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["field_name"]=> array(5) {
    ["name"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=>string(10) "1.png"
      [1]=>string(10) "2.png"
    }
    ["type"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=>string(9) "image/png"
      [1]=>string(9) "image/png"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=>string(26) "/private/var/tmp/phpgg1rgH"
      [1]=>string(26) "/private/var/tmp/phpMe907s"
    }
    ["error"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=>int(0)
      [1]=>int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=>int(928815)
      [1]=>int(871340)
    }
  }
}
```

So as you can see the properties of each file are broken up firstly by the property - not by the file index. Now if you change the structure of the files array like so:

```
$images = [];
foreach( $_FILES[ 'field_name' ] as $prop => $values ){
    foreach( $values as $key => $value ){
        $images[ $key ][ $prop ] = $value;
    }
}
$_FILES = $images;
```

BEFORE you call wp_handle_upload() - everything should work like you expect. That was my issue anyway - not sure if there's a better way to go about solving that error. I have to think this can be solved somehow at the form level rather that overwriting the $_FILES itself. But in a pinch - it fixed my issue.